# Python/DOS: Passing a command as if using the send-to context menu

Tags: python, windows, contextmenu

I really don't know how to word my title better than that, sorry.

I've got an image upscaling converter in the form of a .exe application called waifu2x. The Github page can be found [here](https://github.com/tanakamura/waifu2x-converter-cpp) if you're interested in it.

I'm rewriting a python script I have that runs the image through several applications, the change being that it uses this local application instead of uploading the image to a webserver to do it for me.

Now the application came with a .bat that added *Send To > waifu2x* to my windows context menu, and if I feed it a image or directory in this manner it runs quickly and cleanly. The syntax in this .lnk file is:

```
C:\Users\PathToConverter\w2xcr.exe --block_size 0
```

And if you try to execute w2xcr.exe without passing any arguments it tells you the correct usage syntax is

```
usage: w2xcr.exe [--block_size <size>] <in>
```

Now I presume that *in* refers to the input to the file or folder I'm trying to perform the conversion on. If I try to feed it a full directory "C:\SoOnAndSoForth" I get something to the effect of "directory syntax incorrect", and if I try to give it a local one ("workspace\image.jpg") it simply refuses to function.

**The million dollar question is:** how do I format this such that python will call on w2xcr.exe the same way windows would if I right click > send to > waifu2x?

Apologies for the long-winded explanation, I get the impression this is an easy fix to someone with more experience than I.

Comment: read up on `os.popen`, if you want to run a ping to stack overflow for example do this: `print(os.popen("ping stackoverflow.com").readlines())`

Comment: Dumb question worth asking ... are you escaping your backslashes?

Comment: @TehTris, I'm not really sure how that applies?

Comment: @PhilCairns, yes my backslashes are escaped, but I could still well be having a formatting problem.

Comment: Please remove tag [tag:dos] as it does _not_ apply (I never heard of a right-click context menu in DOS...); moreover, consider to remove tag [tag:batch-file] as well as the question is actually not concerned with such files. Thanks!

Comment: It applies because ping is a cmd line program, and if im not mistaken you are asking how to run a command line program via python?

Comment: DOS is an OS from the 1980s and 1990s. It was tightly coupled to the x86 CPU, being written mostly in assembly language instead of portable C. It was a single user/tasking system in which all code ran in the equivalent of kernel mode without security. Win 2.x was a GUI shell running on DOS. Win 3.x added a 32-bit VMM that, up through Win 9x, gradually replaced DOS at a low level. Win 95 adopted NT's Win32 API, but it often thunked Win32 calls to Win16 and thus DOS. Note that Windows XP and later are NT systems, not DOS, but the cmd.exe shell and batch language are based on DOS COMMAND.COM.

Comment: there is a tag named [tag:cmd], which might be more suitable... just read the respective tag descriptions to learn what they are intended for...